# ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL and am trying to get this query to work:

```
function loadArrayFromQuery($query) {
        $result = $this->executeQuery($query);
        $return = array();
        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $return[] = $rows;
            mysql_error();
        }
        return $return;
    }
```

However i get the following error:

```
ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 56
STR: ->

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'function loadArrayFromQuery($query) {
        $result = $this->executeQuery($query)' at line 1
```

Thanks

Comment: What the heck are you passing as `$query`?

Comment: PS. Why are you using `mysql_error()` with a MySQLi call?  Why is that inside the loop?  What is `executeQuery()`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Examination of the SQL error message (and some experience) shows that he's trying to pass the entire PHP function code as the query. The actual validity of that PHP code is entirely moot, as a consequence. However, you are correct that, even there, multiple errors exist.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm just kinda curious how.  Like is he passing `file_get_contents('file.php')`?  Or did he just (probably) miss a `'` or `"` somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You are currently trying to execute PHP code as an SQL query.**

Unfortunately:

- PHP is not SQL;
- SQL is not PHP.

In case this was an accident rather than a misunderstanding, check for missing `'` or `"` characters at the end of some string higher up your PHP code, as you may accidentally be incorporating code into a query built as a string.

You don't really give enough information in the question to say anything further; except to request, that is, that if you are asking a SQL question please post an SQL query, not PHP code. You ought to spend some time extracting the crux of the problem from the three or four technologies that you're using in your project, so that you are asking *us* about only *one*.